# Not able to generate main-es2015 file after migrating angular project to version 13 from version 12

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I just upgraded my angular project from version 12 to version 13 but now after I run a build, only main.js file is getting created and not main-es2015.js file.
Following are the configs from tsconfig.json
 `"target": "es2015", "module": "esnext"`

I tried enabling aot and vendorChunk flags in angular.json true respectively but no good.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 13 the behavior of differential loading has been updated. As of Angular 13, by default, only the main.js file is created during the build process, and there is no separate main-es5.js or main-es2015.js file. This results in more faster build times.